How to call OpenAi function from python
I generated a function using OpenAI as below:

So the function definition is (json schema):
{
  "name": "generate_jokes",
  "description": "Generate 3 jokes based on input text",
  "strict": true,
  "parameters": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
      "input_text",
      "number_of_jokes"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "input_text": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "The text or context based on which jokes will be generated"
      },
      "number_of_jokes": {
        "type": "number",
        "description": "The number of jokes to generate; default is 3"
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
  }
}

How can I call it in python 3.X?

You can look for documentation here https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/function-calling#overview, for the question 'how?'

What do you mean "call"? You don't call tool definitions -- you let the model call them, then it's your job to give the model the result of that call in your next round of communication. So a tool or function definition doesn't define something for the model to do; instead, it defines something you can do on behalf of the model. (So "generate N jokes" is not a good example of what OpenAI's function calling would be used for, because it's presumably something it's the model's job to carry out).

Now, you could have a function provide_jokes that takes a list of jokes as its argument, and that would be a way to get the model to give you jokes; you could even dynamically generate the jsonschema for the function to set how many jokes something calling it is expected to provide as arguments.

use the json string to initialize your prompt template then pass in formation to the template and invoke openai for the answer
import json
import openai

# Sample JSON input
json_input = '''
{
  "name": "generate_jokes",
  "description": "Generate 3 jokes based on input text",
  "strict": true,
  "parameters": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
      "input_text",
      "number_of_jokes"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "input_text": {
        "type": "string",
        "description": "The text or context based on which jokes will be generated"
      },
      "number_of_jokes": {
        "type": "number",
        "description": "The number of jokes to generate; default is 3"
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
  }
}
'''

# Parse the JSON
data = json.loads(json_input)

# Extract parameters
input_text = "Tell me a joke about programming."
number_of_jokes = 3  # You can change this as needed

# Initialize OpenAI client
client = openai.Client(api_key='your_api_key_here')

# Create a prompt for the OpenAI API
prompt = f"Generate {number_of_jokes} jokes about {input_text}"

# Call the OpenAI API
response = client.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-4o-mini",
    messages=[
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": prompt
        }
    ]
)

# Print the response
for choice in response.choices:
    print(choice.message.content)

